# Pod file shows as a unversioned file

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I installed Googlemap SDK and it works fine. I'm getting the current location and all the details as I needed. But when I tried to commit all changes my Gmap pod file shows as a unversioned files. Can anyone please help me to fix this? Thank you
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9fwr.png)

Comment: Can you post the error message that you get. Also the code that you use.

Comment: I added the files to the project again n it works fine now. Thank u.